# Two tone colours in chart.js pie chart

Tags: jquery, css, charts, chart.js, pie-chart

Have anyone experienced two tone effect in one section of chart.js pie chart, as per the screenshot?

[image: two tone effect]

Any idea how to solve this issue? It does not appear all the time. This is a simple pie chart to display the percentage of gender.

Sorry, I forgot to include the codes.

[JSFIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/dyuLeovr/1/)

```
    var xitems = ['male','female'];
    var yitems = [478,522];
    new Chart(document.getElementById("chartcanvas"), {
                    type: 'pie',
                    data: {
                      labels: xitems,
                      datasets: [
                        {
                          data: yitems,
                          backgroundColor: ["#8DB6CD","#FFB6C1","#DC143C","#800080","#0000FF","#00C5CD","#00EE00","#FFFF00","#FFD700","#FFA500","#8B5A00","#FF4500","#FA8072","#FF3E96",
                          "#BA55D3","#191970","#00FF7F","#B7B7B7","#000000","#006400","#ADFF2F","#EEEE00","#3D59AB","#AB82FF","#CDB5CD","#FF69B4",
                          "#FF0000"],
                          fill: false
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    options: {
                        tooltips: {
                            enabled: false,
                        },
                        showPercentage: true, //Enables percentages on the pie
                    }
                });
```

Comment: please put your code, and try to search in hexadecimal colours in javascript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked at the JS Fiddle and replacing the Chart JS script links worked for me. I used version 2.7.0 instead of 2.4.0 from [CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js).

I'm not sure you need both the libraries either. Just using `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.min.js` should be enough.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. changing to 2.7.0 does help to solve the two tone issue. But it causes another issue, which is the white edges around the pie chart.

Comment: Not sure what could be causing that. I've just had another look at it and created a new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q5wc9wmb/